# How to remove "Confirm Navigation" Pop up in mobile Devices?

Tags: jquery, mobile

How to remove this Navigation alert in mobile devices,

[Confirm Navigation Pop Up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8t9h.png)

Before my website redirect to another url, this alert pops up, am getting this pop up only in Mobile devices, i have checked with couple of android devices.

I have checked some methods posted already here, but it does not works.

how to remove this alert in my website ? Can you please explain what i should do to remove this alert before redirect ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
   return true;
});
```

Comment: you can add which place where it must access on all pages.

Comment: I have tried adding this code, but no success. Here is my Website files details : [Website Files ](https://s4.postimg.org/w3ae4mqkt/website_files.png) Can you please tell me where i should add this code exactly ? Thank you.